# Run powershell as another user

Tags: powershell, gpo

I can't wrap my head around this at all. I have a powershell script that works fine as long as the user has admin rights, because it is moving data to a NAS share that requires write permissions. My issue is I am putting the script in the GPO Startup process. So I need to run the powershell script as another user. 
Do I somehow add the new user credentals inside the script itself, or use another process to runas the other user?
I've tried creating another .ps1 script to start the original script, but it didn't work.
I really want to be able to do this in the original script that's doing all the work.

```
$username = 'domain\user'
$password = 'password'
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

Start-Process -FilePath D:\Scripts\Monitor.ps1 -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred
```

and I've tried:

```
Start-Process -FilePath D:\Scripts\Monitor.ps1 -ComputerName (NAS IP Address) -Credential $cred
```

This works fine inside a powershell script, so how do I get this to run as another user?

```
& D:\Scripts\monitor.ps1
```

Comment: If you are putting this as a computer startup process, I would grant permission to the computer account to write to the target location. Then you don't need to worry about impersonating another user.

Comment: SYSTEM is what is running it from GPO Startup, no way of granting rights to the NAS

Comment: Computer startup scripts run as local system. You should be able to grant a computer's local system permission to access a network path by granting access to the computer's account in AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to run this as a task under task scheduler at boot up run by a service account that has all the correct permissions. Not what I really wanted but it does work

Comment: This should not be necessary if you grant the AD computer account permission to access the network path. It has the additional advantage of being simpler. But in reality this question is really better suited to ServerFault than here.

Comment: Thank you Bill. Originally I wanted to run this in the powershell script as a service account, which is why it was here. My work around works and is being tested in the Development environment